# I don't know why JavaScript function for closing a tab errors out

Tags: angularjs, tabcontrol

In my app I have this in the corresponding Angular controller:

```
     $scope.close_window = function() {
      window.close();
     };
```

The html template has this:

```
    <a href="javascript:close_window();">Quit</a>
```

The button fails to do anything and I see this error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: close_window is not defined

I thought I defined as shown above. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have used a function name without defining. Once you mentioned your function name like the following

```
        <a href="javascript:close_window();">Quit</a>
```

It is not going to look in to the angular scope object. You have defined your function in the scope object but haven't used it correctly. To use this create the command like the following.

```
        <a href="javascript:void();" ng-click="close_window()">Quit</a>
```

Comment: I tried this change and this error comes up: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"